# Is logic a consequence of structure of language i.e. syntax?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, wittgenstein, philosophy-of-logic

I was reading the paper [An elucidatory reading of the Tractatus](https://www.academia.edu/1567265/An_elucidatory_reading_of_the_Tractatus?email_work_card=view-paper)
and in page-3 section- Ineffabilist Readings, it was written

> "The order in our propositions, which renders them capable of thus picturing the facts, we call ‘logic’. Hence, logic can be seen as the order of possible situations in which things can find them-selves as reflected in language".

Can you please approve/disapprove the above fact by Wittgenstein's statements.

Wittgenstein said in *Tractatus* :

> "**6.13** Logic is not a theory, but a reflection of the world. Logic is transcendental".

Is he talking about the structure of language or the logic that we usually study in textbooks?

Comment: When he said *logic is transcendental* I think he meant that language is just the tool we must use to *describe* our logic. *Logic is not a theory, but a reflection of the world* is a great way to explain it. In other words, we can be logical without having the technically correct language with which to describe it to anyone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a reasonable summary of the [Tractarian pictorial view of language](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#TracLogiPhil) :

> **3**  A logical picture of facts is a thought.
>
> **4**  A thought is a proposition with a sense.
>
> **5**  A proposition is a truth-function of elementary propositions.

The world is "made of" *facts* that in turn are made of *objects*.

Objects are "symbolized" by names and a proposition expresses a *thought* (its *sense*) :

> **3.1** In a proposition a thought finds an expression that can be perceived by the senses.
>
> **3.22** In a proposition a name is the representative of an object.

And :

> **4.22** An elementary proposition consists of names. It is a nexus, a concatenation, of names.

The sense of a proposition is related to the fact because the [logical form](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein-atomism/#NamObj) of the linguistic expression "pictures" the structure of the fact.

When W speaks of the *trascendental* nature of logic, he is asserting that logic is not an empirical study of facts (like any other science) but it is prior to our understanding of facts themselves.

In this way, W's reflections on logic - grounded in the pioneering works on logic of Frege and Russell - is quite different from modern approach to mathematcial logic as a mathematical discipline.

Comment: Thank you for such a great answer. So, 'All bachelors are unmarried' is true by the virtue of language. Am I right?

Comment: @adeshmishra - yes; according to the [Analytic–synthetic distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction) it is an "analytic proposition [that] is true by virtue of its meaning".